# How to link my web application to Amadeus

Tags: web-applications, amadeus

I would like to build an application and link it to Amadeus. And what it does is capturing flight tickets from Amadeus and extract data from them (ticket number, passenger's name, date, total amount,....) So that by the end of each month, the agency will have a report of how many tickets have been sold, who purchased the tickets, how much money to pay for the companies,...
My question is: what kind of Amadeus APIs do I need? Do I need to pay for the APIs?

I tried and linked my desktop application with Gmail to capture the emails sent from Amadeus. That actually worked but it wasn't satisfying enough, I want to create a website and link it to Amadeus directly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.